# abstract constructors or equivalent in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics, constructor, abstraction, constructor-overloading

I have some code for a abstract Binary Tree class with nodes. I have an `add(value : N)` method and and `add(value : E)`that just takes an element and automatically creates the Node.

As you can see below the Node is generically typed when you create the tree, I want to change `add(value : E)` to a non-abstract method that will call the Nodes constructor with `value : E` as a parameter.

```kotlin
abstract class BinaryTree<E, N : BinaryTree<E,N>.Node>(var rootNode: N? = null) {

    abstract fun add(node : N) : N
    abstract fun add(value : E) : N


    abstract fun remove(value : E) : N?
    abstract fun remove(node : N) : N
    open fun removeAll(value: E): List<N> {
        val removedNodes: MutableList<N> = mutableListOf()
        var removedNode: N?
        while (remove(value).also { removedNode = it } != null) {
            removedNodes.add(removedNode!!)
        }
        return removedNodes
    }

    abstract inner class Node(var data: E, var left: N?, var right: N?){

        constructor(data: E) : this(data, null, null) {}

        open fun isLeaf(): Boolean{
            return (left == null && right == null)
        }
    }
}
```

I have looked into if there's anything like an abstract constructor that would force the implementation of a `constructor(value : E)` for all subclasses, however I don't think that's a thing.

I'm not sure if there's a way to create that in kotlin. I'm not sure if there's a different solution that would accomplish the same thing.

My problem with leaving it abstract is that it removes the possibility for implementation while leaving subclasses the opportunity to be subclasses further since I would have to remove generic Node typing out in order to call a constructers of that subclass. For example in this implementation BinarySearchTree still deals with a generic Node which is a `BSTNode` but is not abstract so you can't just pass it on to the next subclass:

```
class BinarySearchTree<E : Comparable<E>, N : BinarySearchTree<E,N>.BSTNode>(rootNode: N? = null) : BinaryTree<E, N>(rootNode) {

    override fun add(value : E): N {
        //This can't happen without a generic Node constructor or removing the generic Node type from my default constructor which limits subclasses.
        //I want to be able to call add(N(E)) where N(E) is whatever N's constructor is
    }

    override fun add(node : N) {}

inner class BSTNode(data: E, val parent: N?, left: N? = null, right: N? = null)
        : BinaryTree<E, N>.Node(data, left, right), Comparable<N> {

    //I want to force this in here
    constructor(data: E) : this(data, null, null, null) {}
```

Comment: You can't call the constructor of a generic type without reflection. And if you use reflection, generics aren't buying you anything. There's no way in Kotlin to force a subclass to provide a specific signature of constructor, but that wouldn't help anyway because of my first sentence above.

Answer (score 1):

The node constructor could be a function that subclasses of the tree pass to the parent tree class.

```kotlin
abstract class BinaryTree<E, N : BinaryTree<E,N>.Node>(
    var rootNode: N? = null,
    val createNode: (value: E) -> N,
) {

    abstract fun add(node : N) : N
    
    fun add(value : E) : N = add(createNode(value))

    // ...
}

class SomeTreeClass(
    rootNode: N? = null,
) : BinaryTree<MyValue, MyNode>(rootNode, createNode = { MyNode(it) }) {

    // ...

}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, you're trying to call a generic constructor MyNode(foo : E) and assign it to create node, it's just adding a variable to run into the same issue of being unable to call a constructor. My BinarySearchTree class contains a more constrained Generic. I'll edit the post to clarify.

Comment: This example would work if `MyNode` was a concrete class and you defined the class as `class SomeTreeClass<MyValue>`. Also, you could just put `createNode = ::MyNode`.

Comment: Yes sorry I meant for `SomeTreeClass` to use concrete types. It's the leaf of the hierarchy. Edited